# choose value based on priority list - R data.table

Tags: r, variables, data.table

I have this kind of dataset which many more variables, but I only choose to show a few:

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3, 4, 5),
                 diagnosis1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
                 diagnosis2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
                 diagnosis3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
                 diagnosis4 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

There is 5 patients and 4 types of diagnosis. A patient could have a diagnosis1 but also diagnosis3 (fx patient 5), but in my final dataset each patient are only allowed one diagnosis.
The priority list is this: diagnosis1, diagnosis2, diagnosis3, diagnosis4.
So in this case the patient 5 should only get diagnosis 1.

I have a large dataset with multiple other variables than these 5 shown above. So the output should be the same, but replace the 1's that are not the chosen one to 0.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 3):

Create a vector of your column names, and then use `min(which()` by ID:

#### Update:

specify the dx priority explicitly:

```
dx_priority = c("diagnosis3", "diagnosis1", "diagnosis4", "diagnosis2")
dt[, f_dx:=dx_priority[min(which(.SD==1))], ID, .SDcols = dx_priority]
```

#### Previous answer

let the order of the diagnosis columns dictate the priority

```
dx_cols <- names(dt)[ grepl("^diagnosis", names(dt)) ]
dt[, f_dx := dx_cols[min(which(.SD == 1))], by = ID, .SDcols = dx_cols ]
```

Output:

```
   ID diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3 diagnosis4       f_dx
1:  1          0          1          0          1 diagnosis2
2:  2          0          0          1          0 diagnosis3
3:  3          1          0          1          1 diagnosis1
4:  4          0          1          0          0 diagnosis2
5:  5          1          0          1          0 diagnosis1
```

Comment: I believe the expected output should be "the same, but replace the 1's that are not the chosen one to 0", so I guess not by adding a column but by changing the original datatable

Comment: Thanks! I think it will work! But how does it work if the priority list is different , with this code? what if the priority was like this: diagnosis2, diagnosis1, diagnosis4, diagnosis3?

Comment: instead of using grepl to generate `dx_cols`, just use the priority that you want.. see my edit

Answer (score 2):

```
melt(dt, id.vars = "ID", variable.name = "Diagnosis")[value == 1, .SD[1,1], keyby = ID]

   ID  Diagnosis
1:  1 diagnosis2
2:  2 diagnosis3
3:  3 diagnosis1
4:  4 diagnosis2
5:  5 diagnosis1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the output with the name of the variable, another helpful function is `max.col`, with `ties.method = "first"`:

```r
cols <- names(dt)[grepl("^diagnosis", names(dt))]
dt[, indx := cols[max.col(.SD, ties.method = "first")], .SDcols = cols]

   ID diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3 diagnosis4       indx
1:  1          0          1          0          1 diagnosis2
2:  2          0          0          1          0 diagnosis3
3:  3          1          0          1          1 diagnosis1
4:  4          0          1          0          0 diagnosis2
5:  5          1          0          1          0 diagnosis1
```

You can use `setcolorder` to rearrange the data first if you want a selected priority order:

```r
prio <- c("diagnosis2", "diagnosis1", "diagnosis4", "diagnosis3")
setcolorder(dt, c("ID", prio))[, indx := prio[max.col(.SD, ties.method = "first")], .SDcols = prior]

   ID diagnosis2 diagnosis1 diagnosis4 diagnosis3       indx
1:  1          1          0          0          0 diagnosis2
2:  2          0          0          0          1 diagnosis3
3:  3          0          1          0          0 diagnosis1
4:  4          1          0          0          0 diagnosis2
5:  5          0          1          0          0 diagnosis1
```

---

In base R, you can use `apply`:

```
f <- function(x){
  idx <- min(which(x == 1))
  x[-idx] <- 0
  x
}

dt <- as.data.frame(dt)
dt[-1] <- t(apply(dt[-1], 1, f))
dt

  ID diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3 diagnosis4
1  1          0          1          0          0
2  2          0          0          1          0
3  3          1          0          0          0
4  4          0          1          0          0
5  5          1          0          0          0
```

Comment: Thannks - how does it work if the priority list was different with this code? what if the priority was like this: diagnosis2, diagnosis1, diagnosis4, diagnosis3?

Comment: Check my edit: you can use `setcolorder`

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized over the rows, using a priority vector as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75652187/9463489).

```
bln <- rep(TRUE, nrow(dt))
dx_priority = c("diagnosis1", "diagnosis2", "diagnosis3", "diagnosis4")
dt[
  , c(dx_priority) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x <- x*bln; bln <<- bln & !x; x}),
  .SDcols = dx_priority
][]
#>    ID diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3 diagnosis4
#> 1:  1          0          1          0          0
#> 2:  2          0          0          1          0
#> 3:  3          1          0          0          0
#> 4:  4          0          1          0          0
#> 5:  5          1          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dt %>% 
  transmute(ID, Diagnosis = invoke(coalesce, across(starts_with("diagnosis"), 
    ~ case_match(.x, 1 ~ cur_column()))))
```

-output

```
 ID  Diagnosis
1:  1 diagnosis2
2:  2 diagnosis3
3:  3 diagnosis1
4:  4 diagnosis2
5:  5 diagnosis1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `set()`:

```
# Define column priority
pr  <- paste0("diagnosis", 1:4)

tmp <- dt[[pr[1]]]
for (i in 2:length(pr)) {
  set(dt, i = which(tmp == 1), j = pr[i], value = 0)
  tmp <- pmax(tmp, dt[[pr[i]]])
}

#       ID diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3 diagnosis4
#    <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>
# 1:     1          0          1          0          0
# 2:     2          0          0          1          0
# 3:     3          1          0          0          0
# 4:     4          0          1          0          0
# 5:     5          1          0          0          0
```